# Why do hidden windows restore slightly to the right after I close the lid and go to sleep?

Tags: macbook-pro

Workflow: During the day I have a 27" external monitor attached. I get to the office, plug it in to the monitor, load my Windows development VM, and it immediately attaches to the external monitor (as I like, that part is fine). However, any windows I had been working on the night before, such as my Chrome windows, or Sublime Text, always start just slightly to the right of where they were last night. I adjust them back to where I want them, keep working. At the end of the day I close my VM, unplug that monitor, close the laptop, go home, get it back out do some more work, then hide the windows before going to bed so my workspace is free and clear in the morning, and not remnants of the previous night.

This is what I normally have things look like:

[image]

And this is how they look when they "shift on unhide":

[image]

Drawing attention to the newly unhidden Sublime Text 2 window, that is now on top of Chrome. Last night it was fairly aligned with Chrome, and I hid both apps. This morning I unhid Chrome, fixed it's position for a screenshot, and then unhid ST2. I did not "move" ST2 from where it unhid-to, but it's assuredly not where I left it. See how it's still at the top of the window, it's just *shifted* to the right a bit? I move it back and I'm just where I was.

Comment: Feel free to add tags or retitle the question. I'm very much a noob to OSX and can't even quite describe what the hell the issue here is.

Comment: I also feel fairly confident the issue is because I use my dock on the side, which feels natural to me on this system, mostly because I need more vertical real-estate most days. So if the price I pay for vertical real-estate is having to move my windows every single day (until Apple decides this needs to be "fixed") then so be it.